# Cutoff at critical point is extremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U$ be some domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $0\in U$. We have some $C^2$ function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla f(0)=\mathbf{0}$, therefore 0 is a critical point (i.e. local maximum, local minimum or saddle point). Define $U^+=:\{\mathbf{x}\in U: x_n\geq 0 \}$ and $f^+: U^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x)$.

Is $0$ an extremum of $f^+$ and if yes how could we prove it?

For example, in case of $n=1$ we have $U=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^3$. Then $0$ is a saddle point of $f$, but $0$ is obviously a local (and global) minimum of $f^+: [0,\infty) \rightarrow x^3$. How could I prove this (and in the general case)?

Thank you for any ideas and pointers.

Comment: You mean if $U = \mathbb{R}^2$, then $U^+ = \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty)$, right?

Comment: Well in that case $n$ would be 2, and we would need a function $f$ that takes 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

No. As a counterexample, take a function $f_0 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with a saddle at the origin (e. g. $f_0(x) = x^3$) and then
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x, y) = f_0(x), $$
its constant extension in $y$-direction.
Then the point $0$ is a critical point of $f$ and its cutoff $f^+$ to non-negative second coordinate $\{y \geq 0\}$ still does not have an extremum in $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ (because $f(x, 0) = f_0(x)$ has a saddle in $x=0$).

The one-dimensional case is special though and your statement works. The proof is by the monotonicity criterion from the Mean Value Theorem (see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Function_with_Positive_Derivative_is_Increasing).

Comment: I might have poorly worded my question. $f^+$ should be the restriction of $f$ onto the same set but with positive last coordinate. In your counterexample $f_0$ is 1-dimensional, but $f$ is 2-dimensional. But I think my claim is still wrong. I need to think about it a bit and will update my question accordingly, thank you.

Comment: $y \geq 0$ means restricting to non-negative last coordinate. The counterexample is $f$, not $f_0$ (from which it is built).